# Java - Problema con condicional

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
   public class UnitatFamiliar extends Thread {

    Comandament comandament;

    public UnitatFamiliar(Comandament c) {
        comandament = c;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Agafa el comandament
        comandament.agafa();
        int canal = (int) ((Math.random() * 5) + 1); //triem un canal al·leatoriament, entre el 1 i el 100

        Comandament CanalFinal = new Comandament();
        CanalFinal.setCanal(canal);

        if (canal == comandament.getCanal()) {
            comandament.setCanal(canal);
        } else {
            System.out.println(getName() + " està mirant el canal " + canal);
        }
        //Mira la tele
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 350) + 300);  //utilitzem el mètode sleep per suspendre l'execució del Thread un temps aleatori de ms
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
        }
        //Deixa el comandament
        comandament.deixa();
    }
}
```

Tengo algo mal y no sé que puede ser.
La idea es:

```
  - Si el canal es diferente al canal que hay actualmente, muestra un mensaje.
  - Si es igual, entonces no hagas nada.
```

El problema es que siempre muestra el canal... ¿qué tengo mal?

--- EDITO CON LA PARTE DE CÓDIGO QUE FALTA:

```
    public class Comandament  {
   /*
    * Modifiqueu i afegiu el codi necessari per implementar la classe 
    * Comandament.
    */
    boolean avalible = true;
    int canal;

          public int getCanal()
        {
                return canal;
        }
        public void setCanal(int canal)
        {
                this.canal = canal;
        }

    synchronized void agafa() {

    while (avalible == false) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    avalible = false;
    notify();
}

        synchronized void deixa() {
    avalible = true;
    notify();
}
    }
```

Comment: canal nunca es 0.. y UnitatFamiliar.canal parece ser siempre 0... o sea.. siempre son diferentes!

Comment: La variable local canal es un numero aleatorio mayor a 1 y lo comparas con la variable estatica canal que tiene valor 0.

Comment: entiendo lo que me decís pero no se como hacer para que el programa funcione si no lo hago así.. T_T

Comment: Tu variable canal ponle un numero mayor a cero, 5 por ejemplo en numero aleatorio en algún momento saldrá 5 y serán igual mientras sea cero no pasara. pero podrías describir un poco mas para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Como dicen por aqui, siempre te va a mostrar el canal, pues estas generando un numero aleatorio que siempre va a ser >=1 y lo comparas con un numero 0. Explica un poco mas lo que necesitas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: lo que necesito es que le de un numero aleatorio. y si el numero aleatorio se repite que no diga nada elprograma. Pero si es el mismo diga : Esta mirando el mismo canal de televisión

Comment: editada.. haber si podéis ver como puedo hacerlo.. T_T

Answer (score 1):

Muy probablemente el atributo `canal` deberia ser miembro de otra clase.

Tienes:

- `UnitatFamiliar extends Thread`, que al parecer modela una persona, un miembro de la familia
- `Comandament`, un recurso compartido por todos los threads, al parecer el control de la television

El canal que actualmente esta siendo visto deberia ser un atributo de `Comandament` y no de `UnitatFamiliar`

Por lo que tu comparacion en esta linea:

```
if (canal != UnitatFamiliar.canal){ ... }
```

Deberia ser algo como:

```
if (canal != comandament.getCanal()){
    comandament.setCanal(canal);
    ...
}
```

Comment: no me funciona he probado pero el getCanal no existe.. voy super perdida.. T_T

Comment: pues claro que no existe: "El canal que actualmente esta siendo visto deberia ser un atributo de `Comandament`" tienes que agregar el atributo a `Comandament` y crear su respectivo *getter* y *setter*

Comment: acabo de hacer lo que me dices pero sigo haciendo algo mal.. Puedes decirme que puede ser? :(

Comment: Pusiste `==` en lugar de `!=`

Comment: aunque ponga != me va mal.. Es decir el programa tiene que ver que si el canal es el mismo ( es decir por random nos da un canal.. pues si ese vuelve a ser el mismo no dirá nada.. ) Y no me funciona.. T_T

Comment: Supongo que cuando lo editaste lo dejaste como: `if (canal != comandament.getCanal()) {
            comandament.setCanal(canal);
            System.out.println(getName() + " està mirant el canal " + canal);
        }` cierto?

Comment: si! Más arriba puedes ver los cambios y justo eso puse..

Comment: voy algo perdida perdon :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74454/discussion-between-klaimmore-and-montse-mkd).

Answer (score -1):

Intenta hacer una instancia de tu `UnitatFamiliar` ya que al no instanciarlo no se está corriendo el constructor y por lo tanto tu `UnitatFamiliar.canal` no tiene un valor inicial.
Lo instancias de esta manera `unita = new UnitatFamiliar()`

Comment: puedes detallarmelo mas? no acabo de entenderte.

Comment: el valor por defecto de int es 0 cuando no esta inicializado (lo inicializa el compilador por defecto)